# How to create dynamic add input field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to create a dynamic add input field when user type insde the input the add button will available to click on. And after click on add it will appear another input field.

Here is how the it look like:

[image]

and here is what I have implemented:

```
  const [inputs, setInputs] = useState(
    teamData.rules.map((value) => ({
      value,
      guid: uuidV4(),
    }))
  );

  const addInputs = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setInputs((inputs) => [
      ...inputs,
      {
        name: `rule_${inputs.length + 1}`,
        guid: uuidV4(),
      },
    ]);
  };
  const removeInputs = (index) => {
    const newList = inputs.filter((item, i) => index !== i);
    setInputs(newList);
  };
  const clearInput = (dataName) => {
    setUpdateTeamData((prevState) => {
      delete prevState[dataName];
      return {
        ...prevState,
      };
    });
  };

<div>
  {inputs?.map((data, idx) => {
    return (
      <div className="agreement-form-grid" key={data.guid}>
        <button
          type="button"
          className="agreement-remove-button"
          onClick={() => {
            removeInputs(idx);
            clearInput(`rule_${idx}`);
          }}
        >
          <Remove />
        </button>
        <input
          name={`rule_${idx}`}
          onChange={handleChange}
          placeholder={`Rule ${idx + 1}`}
          defaultValue={teamData.rules[idx]}
        />
      </div>
    );
  })}
```

[image]

How can I achieve the feature like the first picture?

Answer (score 1):

you need two variable. One is an array storing the list of added rules, and the second one is the string for keeping the value of the rule that is not yet added to the array:

```
const [rules, setRules] = useState([{ value: "test", id: 0 }]);
  const [preAddedRule, setPreAddedRule] = useState("");
```

Then, by relying on these functions you can add and remove rules to your variables:

```
const handleRemove = (id) => {
    setRules(rules.filter((rule, i) => rule.id !== id));
  };
  const handleAdd = (id) => {
    setRules([...rules, { value: preAddedRule, id: rules.length }]);
    setPreAddedRule("");
  };
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setPreAddedRule(e.target.value);
  };
```

Just remember to clear the value of the `preAddedRule` after adding it to array, in order to prepare it for the next rules.

And finally, display all your rules, inputs and buttons as below:

```
{rules.map((el, i) => (
        <div>
          <input value={el.value} />
          <button onClick={() => handleRemove(el.id)}>delete</button>
        </div>
      ))}
      <input onChange={handleChange} value={preAddedRule} />
      <button onClick={() => handleAdd()}>Add</button>
```

[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-nash-kl83v?file=/src/App.js:553-838)

Comment: I already had the handleAdd which is addInputs do you think I need to change that?

Comment: Hmm, It seems fine. Just also remember to store `event.target.value` in `addInputs` function, as it was missing I think.

Comment: Can we get rid of the preAddValue?

Comment: If you go to this website https://paperscore.org/ and create a manuscript you can see how the add input looks like. I am trying to achieve it like that

Comment: you can. you can store it in the `rules` array, but you need to add another attribute to `rules` to know whether that specific rule is added or not. Or you can rely on the existence of the id attribute. Up to you

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't get your comment about paperscore.org website. Does my code solve the question and sandbox link work for you? Or I'm missing something?

Comment: Not quite. But how can I make the `preAddValue` turn into the current input value like. When I add input rule 1 and then the `prevalue` should be rule 2

Comment: `handleAdd` function do this

Comment: Please check the code and sandbox, as they solve all that you mentioned in the question :)

Comment: Yea it worked. But when I add     `setPreAddedRule(event.target.value);` in my `handleChange` and then I hit submit It did not get any data from the input